# How do i paste into another file through app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this code:

```
function copyInfo() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Product-analyse");  
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Blad18"); // get source range  
var source = copySheet.getRange(93,7,39,6);  // get destination range  
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,39,6); // copy values to destination range  
source.copyTo(destination);  // clear source values
source.clearContent();
}
```

1. Now its pasting in "Blad18". Instead I want it to be pasted in another file.
2. I tried adding {contentOnly: TRUE}. Though this didnt seem to work

I cannot figure this out unfortunately. Everything else is correctly set already.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Updated script I am using:

```
function copyInfo() {  
  var ssSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var copySheet = ssSource.getSheetByName("Product-analyse"); 
  var ssPaste = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qhnA8L3ZkU-iEyOJtszAC4OW58sg2TJZSa_rmN_EXBI"); // the id of the other spreadsheet
  var pasteSheet = ssPaste.getSheetByName("Submitted Data"); // get source range  
  var source = copySheet.getRange(93,7,39,6);  // get destination range  
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,39,6); // copy values to destination range  
  source.copyTo(destination);  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: You need to specify a little what you mean by another file. Are you intending to copy to a different spreadsheet entirely? If that is the case you simply need something like `ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetByURL()` or `ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById()` to work with sheets on that file

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var psh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const cshsr = 2;
  var crg = csh.getRange(cshsr, 1, csh.getLastRow() - cshsr + 1, csh.getLastColumn());
  var prg = psh.getRange(psh.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
  crg.copyTo(prg); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is copy from one spreadsheet file to another spreadsheet file.  Here is an example

```
function copyInfo() {  
  var ssSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var copySheet = ssSource.getSheetByName("Product-analyse"); 
  var ssPaste = SpreadsheetApp.openById("dfsfhsfhskfhaskjfhsjkfas"); // the id of the other spreadsheet
  var pasteSheet = ssPaste.getSheetByName("Blad18"); // get source range  
  var source = copySheet.getRange(93,7,39,6);  // get destination range  
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,39,6); // copy values to destination range  
  source.copyTo(destination);  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

Reference

- [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

Comment: The current script gives me an error 

I am using the updated script in the question.

Im getting the following error: Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.
copyInfo @ SubmitData.gs:9